# How to build a C++ Stack structure

Tags: c++, stack

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    Node *next;
    Node(int val) :value(val), next(nullptr){}
};
class Stack
{
public:
    void push(int val);
    int pop();
    bool is_empty(){ return first == nullptr; }
private:
    Node *first = nullptr;
};

int Stack::pop(){
    int ret = first->value;
    first = first->next;
    return ret;
}
void Stack::push(int i){
    if (is_empty()){
        first = &Node(i);
        return;
    }
    Node oldFirst = *first;
    first = &Node(i);
    first->next = &oldFirst;
}
```

Here is how I wrote the code, however, there is a problem that when I finished `push()` the pointer of `first` isn't point to the right object. I'm wondering how I can solve that problem.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `std::stack<int>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `&Node(i)` creates a ***temporary*** object and give you a pointer to it. And then the temporary object is immediately destructed, leaving you with a pointer to a non-existing object.

You need to use `new` to allocate a new object.

You have a similar problem with `&oldFirst`, which give you a pointer to a *local* variable, which will be destructed once the function returns. You need to use a pointer variable.